# PHP script taking to long to run for jQuery/AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have written a script in PHP to pull data using AXLAPI and then using that data to be displayed in a table.

I run the script in the command line and everything works fine. Takes about 7 seconds to complete.

When i try to run the script from an AJAX, it only displays the headings to the table and none of the information.

I think this is happening because the PHP script is taking too long to run. I dont see any errors in my error log and nothing in the developer tools on chrome.

Does anyone know of away to make the AJAX wait till the PHP script is complete?

This is how i currently call my PHP script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#cucm').blur(function(){

var cucm = $('#cucm').val();



    $.ajax({
        url: "scripts/getPhones.php",
        type:'POST',
        data: {"value1": cucm},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(responce){
                $("#phones").html(responce);
            } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call 

    });

</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    include_once "connectdb.php";

    $cucm = $_POST["value1"];

    $tbquery = "select DISTINCT * from CUCM where Name='$cucm'";

    $db = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "[password]");
    mysql_select_db("DNA", $db);
    $result = mysql_query($tbquery) or die('SQL Error :: '.mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $host = $row['IP'];
    $username = $row['User'];
    $password = $row['Pass'];
    $ver = $row['Ver'];

    class NoticeException extends Exception { 
        public function __toString() {
            return  "Notice: {$this->message} {$this->file} on line {$this->line}n";
        }
    }



    $client = new SoapClient("axlsql/schema/$ver/AXLAPI.wsdl",

        array('trace'=>true,

            'exceptions'=>true,

            'location'=>"https://$host:8443/axl",

            'login'=>$username,

            'password'=>$password,

        ));

    $response = $client->listPhone(

        array("searchCriteria"=>

            array("name"=>"%"),

                "returnedTags" =>

                array("name"=>"")

            )

        );


    $phones = $response->return->phone;

    set_error_handler("error_handler", E_ALL);

    function error_handler($errno, $errstr) {
        if($errno == E_WARNING) {
            throw new WarningException($errstr);
        } else if($errno == E_NOTICE) {
            throw new NoticeException($errstr);
        }
    }

    try {
        $n = 0;

        $output_string ="<table id=\"table\" class=\"table table-striped\"\n";
        $output_string .="<thead>\n";
        $output_string .="<tr>\n";
        $output_string .="<th>Phone Name</th>\n";
        $output_string .="<th>Line Pattern</th>\n";
        $output_string .="<th>Line CSS</th>\n";
        $output_string .="<th></th>\n";
        $output_string .="</tr>\n";
        $output_string .="</thead>\n";
        $output_string .="<tbody>\n";
        $output_string .="<tr>\n";

        while(True) {
            $phone = $phones[$n]->name;

            $response = $client->getPhone(array("name"=>"SEP5CFC665D1DAF"));
            $line = $response->return->phone->lines->line->dirn->uuid;
            $pattern = $response->return->phone->lines->line->dirn->pattern;
            $response = $client->getLine(array("uuid"=>$line));

            try {

                $css = $response->return->line->shareLineAppearanceCssName->value;

            }catch(Exception $e) {

                $css = "No Line CSS";

            }

            $output_string .="<tr>\n";
            $output_string .="<td id=\"phone$n\" value=\"$phone\">$phone</td>\n";
            $output_string .="<td id=\"line$n\">$pattern</td>\n";
            $output_string .="<td id=\"css$n\">$css</td>\n";
            $output_string .="<td></td>\n";
            $output_string .="</tr>\n";
            $n++;
        }

    } catch(Exception $e) {

        $output_string .="</tr>\n";
        $output_string .="</tr>\n";
        $output_string .="</tbody>\n";
        $output_string .="</table>\n";
        $output_string .="<br>";

    } 


echo json_encode($output_string);

?>
```

Thanks,
Kristian

Comment: Your ajax call is expecting json to be returned. If you are returning html then change the dataType

Comment: I'd want to see your PHP. I suspect it's not returning what your AJAX is expecting it to.

Comment: "I have written a script in PHP that is taking too long" - proceeds to not post the PHP code lol

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another host, and it can be helpful to take json instead html, like a say @FunkDoc in comment, and after parse it with jquery.

And for what exactly you do this (Json from Html)

```
echo json_encode($output_string);
```